# Wordpress menus: Change URLs

Tags: menus, themes, child-theme

I am new to Wordpress. I use it with Avada and Avada Child Themes. I have not set up the site, I only administrate it. In the following I will name all pages (sites, products, calender, ...) as "sites".

**Problem**:
I want to change the URLs in the main menu bar, in the sidebar (only on mobiles??) and everywhere where is an outgoing to a specific site, lets say *site A*.
Some links/URLs are wrong.
Is there any way to see from where are outgoing links to the site A?

**I tried:**
I tried in Design -> menus, there I can see the navigatio menu and submenus, but I do not see any URLs, only names of the sites, options to place them up and down etc.

Custom Links are all empty.
Where do I change the wrong URLs?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of what you want to achieve. Do you mean you will have one word site in navigation and it can link to different pages?